# enum class of type string in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class

**- Background Information:**

There is a class in C++11 known as enum class which you can store variables inside. However, I have only seen the type of the class to be char:

```
enum class : char {
   v1 = 'x', v2 = 'y'
};
```

---

**- Question:**

Is there any way I can express this enum class of type string?

For example,

```
enum class : string{
  v1 = "x", v2 = "y"
};
```

---

**- What I think:**

I tried using it, but I got errors, I am not sure if I am doing it right or not. The reason why I want to use strings is that they are capable of holding multiple characters at the same time, so it makes them more useful for my code.

Comment: @CinCout Everything in your comment is incorrect. Underlying type of a scoped enum is `int` only if you haven't specified a type, which is not the case in the example above. And `char` is certainly not an `int`.

Comment: @Kourosh *There is a class in C++11 known as enum class* ... no, there's no such class, `enum class` is used for defining scoped enumerations. The answers below link to documentation that explains what those are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to do that in C++11 or C++14. However, you should consider having some [enum class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), then code some explicit functions or operators to convert it from and to `std::string`-s.

> There is a class in C++11 known as enum class which you can store variables inside.

That phrasing is not correct: an enum class does not store variables (but *enumerators*).

So you might code:

```
enum class MyEnum : char {
   v1 = 'x', v2 = 'y'
};
```

(this is possible, as [answered by druckermanly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43510676/841108), because `char` is an *integral type*; of course you cannot use strings instead)

then define some `MyEnum string_to_MyEnum(const std::string&);` function (it probably would throw some exception if the argument is an unexpected string) and another `std::string MyEnum_to_string(MyEnum);` one. You might even consider also having some [cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) calling them (but I don't find that readable, in your case). You could also define a `class MyEnumValue` containing one single data member of `MyEnum` type and have that class having [cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), e.g.

```
 class MyEnumValue {
    const MyEnum en;
 public:
    MyEnumValue(MyEnum e) : en(e) {};
    MyEnumValue(const std::string&s)
     : MyEnumValue(string_to_MyEnum(s)) {};
    operator std::string () const { return MyEnum_to_string(en);};
    operator MyEnum () const { return en };
    //// etc....
 };
```

With appropriate more things in `MyEnumValue` (see the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) you might almost always use `MyEnumValue` instead of `MyEnum` (which perhaps might even be internal to `class MyEnumValue`)

Comment: Ok I see, maybe It would be better to say hold variables ?

Comment: No, better use the standard terminology of *enumerators*.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum states:

> The values of the constants are values of an integral type known as the underlying type of the enumeration.

The key point being "integral type" -- a string is not an integral type.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler internally converts your char to its equivalent int representation (ASCII). So it would not be possible to use string instead.